# NSOutlineView selectionIsChanging on mouse up

Tags: macos, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I've got a Mac app involving an `NSOutlineView`. The view controller containing the outline view implements `outlineViewSelectionIsChanging:` to set selection state in a custom way on the cells in the outline view (it's view-based). But `selectionIsChanging` is called on mouse up, not mouse down. I've got other view controllers with other outline views in the app that get `selectionIsChanging` properly on mouse down, but I can't find  a difference. Is this a property on `NSOutlineView` / `NSTableView`? Or is there another probable cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that if drag-and-drop is implemented on the outline view, it only posts selection messages on mouse up.